Member RTCIceServer.urls is required and must be an instance of (DOMString or sequence)
Error reporting member RTCIceServer. When using WebRTC on a Mac computer, the URL is required and must be an instance of (DOMString or sequence)
I hope to have a normal conversation, but I can't. This is the most headache inducing problem for me

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have regenerated a new RTCPeerConnection, which has returned to normal, but there is a new issue where an anwer cannot be created on the Safari browser.
